# Print content of a dictionary of arrays to sheet

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I'm trying to print the contents of a dictionary of arrays in one fell swoop to an Excel sheet.

The dictionary structure may be something like this:
`dict(company_name) = employee`
Where employee is an array of three values, e.g., name, surname, and age.

As long as the items are single value, I can print the dictionary with a statement like

```vb
Cells(1, 1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
Cells(1, 2).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
```

I cannot come up with a solution when I have array as item.

Comment: I don't think that this can work in VBA with a single command. You will have to loop over the dictionary and write the data row by row

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error. dict.Keys - it's an array of the keys! You can't set the cell value as array
You need to set the string variable and collect all keys in it

```
Dim str1 as String
Dim str2 as String
For i=1 to count 'qty of elements in dictionary
str1=str1 & dict.Keys()(i) 
str2=str2 & dict.Items()(i) 
Next i
```

Here is the link to the article about dictionaries

http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html

Answer (score 0):

With a loop you can do something like this - should still be fast.

```vb
Sub DictOutput()
    
    Dim dict As Object, i As Long, r As Long, cols As Long, col As Long, arr, data, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    'load some test data
    For i = 1 To 100
        dict.Add "Key_" & Format(i, "000"), Split("A,B,C,D", ",")
    Next i
    
    arr = dict.Items()(0)                        'get the first value
    cols = 1 + (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr))       'number of items in array (assumed all the same size)
    ReDim data(1 To dict.Count, 1 To (1 + cols)) 'size the output array
    r = 0
    
    For Each k In dict 'loop and fill the output array
        r = r + 1
        data(r, 1) = k
        arr = dict(k)
        i = 2
        For col = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'loop array and populate output row
            data(r, i) = arr(col)
            i = i + 1
        Next col
    Next k
    
    'put the data on the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
End Sub
```